# How do I get a list of all the categories and channels inside the current server with discord.py in discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want an output that will output all the (category names and ids + channel names and ids)inside the server that the bot is in.

The code might look something like this:

```py
    # catetories
    @client.command()
    async def list_catetories(ctx):
      for category in discord.categories:
        print('id: ' + category.id + ', name: ' + category.name)

    # channels
    @client.command()
    async def channels(ctx):
      for channel in discord.channels:
        print('id: ' + channel.id + ', name: ' + channel.name)
```

## Solution

```py
# categories
@client.command()
async def cat(ctx):
    for category in ctx.message.guild.categories:
        print(category.name)

# text channels
@client.command()
async def txtChannel(ctx):
    for text_channel in ctx.message.guild.text_channels:
        print(text_channel.name)

#voice channels
@client.command()
async def vc(ctx):
    for voice_channel in ctx.message.guild.voice_channels:
        print(voice_channel.name)

#all channels + categories
@client.command()
async def channels(ctx):
    for channel in ctx.message.guild.channels:
        print(channel.name)
```

Answer (score -3):

There are multiple channel types, so the following code will show `all` channels. If you want to filter by type you should check the type of it

```py
@client.command()
async def channels(ctx):
  for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
    print(f"Name: {channel.id} Id: {channel.id}")
```

Comment: Is there a way to list all categories?